# Load balancing WebSocket with Redis and RabbitMQ

Tags: redis, socket.io, architecture, rabbitmq, microservices

Consider a small chat server. In this server, the actual processing of messages is done by nodes of a service called "chat". Communications of this service along with a "user" service are then aggregated via a "gateway" service in front that is the only service that actually communicates with the users and is in charge of passing requests received to other services via the RabbitMQ channel they share.

In a system designed like this, each user is connected to one of the instances of the "gateway" service and when sending and receiving messages indirectly communicates with the private "chat" or "user" services behind. To load balance this, we have an Nginx reverse-proxy on the edge that tries to distribute requests to different "gateway" instances. But since WebSocket connection is real-time, "chat" instances should also be able to send messages to the right instance of the "gateway" in charge of that specific user for user-specific messages and to all "gateway" instances for site-wide messages. This is a problem since with RabbitMQ I don't believe we can target a specific subscriber and even if we could, we don't know to which instance that specific user is connected right now.

Therefore, since we are using Socket.io for WebSocket connection, I am thinking of adding a new Redis node to the stack to allow this communication between different instances of the "gateway" service. This is directly supported by Socket.io and works alright and removes all sorts of limitations imposed by the RabbitMQ, however, we are still using RabbitMQ to route a message from a "chat" instance to a "gateway" instance that then will propagate through the Redis service and when the right "gateway" instance having access to the user is found, delivered to them.

This adds unnecessary lag to user-specific outbound messages. So here I am asking if anyone has a better idea of how this problem should be approached and how to decrease this lag.

Personally, I have this idea of adding Socket.io to "chat" services (with no client access) and use its backend to send the message directly to the Redis store so that the instance of the "gateway" connected to it can route it directly to the user, going over the whole RabbitMQ thing for this type of messages.

It might be important to mention that none of these services are here just to do this specific thing, RabbitMQ is heavily used for communication between different services acting as the message broker and the "gateway" service works with multiple other services for data aggregation, authentication and data validation and transformation. The above example was a simplified version of the problem at hand with the minimum number of moving parts that I could easily describe here.

[image]

---

*Edit*: To send messages directly to socket.io redis store, the following library can be used apparently not to load the whole socket.io library:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis-emitter

Comment: I think I understand your situation at a high level - just for clarity, what's the exact problem you think you need help with the most?

Comment: WebSockets - is that between User-Gateway only, or does it extend all the way to Redis?

Comment: @AdrianK, the problem is that by sending the message to RabbitMQ so that it reaches one of the gateways and then broadcasted over Redis to be captured by the right instance of the gateway and sent to the user adds lag. I was hoping that someone suggests a new way so that I can somehow decrease this delay. Not to mention that it doesn't help with the saturation of the RabbitMQ queue. 
My own suggestion was to send these responses directly to Redis to be picked up by the right Gateway instance.
Websocket is only User-Gateway, but Socket.io uses Redis to find the right instance of the Gateway.

Comment: @AdrianK, and really, I decided to ask this question here so that if I am missing something obvious or a better way to design this architecture someone points me in the right direction. Considering the fact that I did not get any answer makes me believe that I am in the right path and just have to optimize it better.

Comment: @SoroushFalahati What is the challenge in creating topics for the messages in the rabbitmq brokers and using that as pub/sub between your chat and the gateway? You'd be doing the same thing if you'd be using Redis using socket.io (this is what happens behind the scenes, sort of).

Comment: @RahulSharma, fair point, however, I then have to manage message routing to find the right gateway instead of just queueing messages. I also have to write a rabbitmq-adapter for socket.io,  My thinking was that using Redis with socket.io since it is officially supported is more advantageous. But my hope was to find out an easier and better way :)